# Lagrange's method of multiplication

Tags: calculus, optimization

This question is about finding stationary points of a function subject to a constraint. The function is $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3$ and the constraint is an ellipse, $x^2+2y^2=3$. I have found my stationary points and they are:

- $(0, rt3/rt2)$

  $(0, -rt3/rt2)$
- $(rt3, 0)$
- $(-rt3, 0)$
- $(1/rt3, 2/rt3)$
- $(-1/rt3, -2/rt3)$

Firstly, I am struggling with the classification of these points. I have input these points into the original function f to try and get a feel for which values are bigger than others. I am finding it complicated to see if i have saddle, min or max. Does anyone have a (visual) method for determining type?

Secondly, what would be the MINIMUM value INSIDE the ellipse (so $x^2+2y^2\leq3$)?

Thanks.

Comment: thank you but i have used them already! there are some really useful questions and I have got the hang of this topic mostly, but that doesn't help me much, especially for finding a minimum inside the ellipse: i am not entirely sure what that even means!

Comment: sorry-root. I couldnt figure out how to use symbols!

Comment: square root sorry yes!

Comment: waldorf, there are 6 points $(0;\pm \sqrt{3/2}),\, (\pm \sqrt{3}; 0),\, \pm(\sqrt3/3;2\sqrt3/3)$ lying on the border and 1 point $(0;0)$ inside. That are all the points to choose MIN and MAX.

Comment: ok i am happy with the border points. How do you pick (0, 0) as the inside point?